# Perform a specific function on Each page load with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am making an application in vb.net2008. I am using a webbrowser control in which opening a website. I want that on each web page load of website, my application performs a specific function programatically. Like

1) When we open www.yahoo.com then after the page is fully loaded, my program should click the sign in button programatically .

2) After that when the next page for prompting the username and password  is loaded, my program should enter the username and the password automtically.

3) And after logged in, my program should click the mail link programatically.

Comment: Stackoverflow users are not here to solve your problems, they are here to try to help you where you get stuck while trying to solve your problem. So you need to edit your question and add what you have tried and where you found problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
'Operation 1
WebBrowser1.Navigate "http://www.yahoo.com/"
Do Until WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete    
 DoEvents
Loop


'Operation 2, signing in
WebBrowser1.Document.getElementById("Username").Value = "MyUsername"
WebBrowser1.Document.getElementById("Password").Value = "Password"
WebBrowser1.Document.getElementById("buttonLogOn").Click


Do Until WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete 
DoEvents
Loop

'Operation 3
Dim link as HtmlElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementByID("mailLink")
link.InvokeMember("Click")

End Sub
```

Instead of the `Do Until WebBrowser1.ReadyState =` it is much better to use the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event of your webbrowser control. I will leave this exercise to you.

Comment: be warned, however, that the document completed event may fire multiple times - ex: for sites with frames. A somewhat improved solution is to use the documentCompleted event, but to "exit sub" if WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete